# C# How change the control (in dll) which already compiled

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, properties, controls

I'm using a library which contain a few controls for WPF C#! Some caption of buttons and tooltips for controls are in English, but I want to change the text and caption of these controls to another language. One control contain a few buttons and a don't have an access to them! There is no any property like "Language" or something else. Cuktury Info I could change but I don'r know the structure of control! Can I change these controls?
Controls are containing in the dynamic link library! 
Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation: Decompile the dll and manually change the designer/xaml, then recompile (assuming you have all dependencies).

There are a several free decompilers for .NET. I typically use ILSpy.

Comment: It's not my control! U recomendate to decompile! Ok! Now I try! Thanks for your answer!